# For anything I care

Tags: expressions

> I’ll interfere in no quarrels between you and Nelly.  She may thrust
>   you into the coal-hole for anything I care.

Does this have similar meaning with "I don't care whether she thrust you into the coal-hole or not."?

Is this expression idiomatic or some kind of a shortened form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contemporary American English, it would be "for *all* I care".

You have understood the meaning. It means that my care is such that I would not object to her throwing you into the coal-hole. I care very little or not at all.

> You can go jump in a lake, for all I care.
>
> You can sit there moping until Doomsday, for all I care.
>
> You can vandalize his other car too, for all I care. He always takes my parking spot.